# OpenVPN install - Missing expected CA file/ EasyRSA error

Tags: 18.04, openvpn, mate

Hey everyone it's my first time installing a VPN on my Celeron powered Intel NUC with a clean install of Ubuntu mate 18.04 LTS. And I can't get past this ca file requirement. I have followed the commands to input from digital ocean exactly the way they wanted. But for some reason I'm getting an EasyRSA error, and I'm not getting what's pictured in their tutorial. Any help would be greatly appreciated, because I'm totally lost. Thanks.

[Link to Guide I'm following](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04) (I'm on step #3)

[Screenshots of Terminal](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/70gy9b6pbijw53j/AACJ9_9dh5C23hbg75fE3bUDa?dl=0)

```
noah@Ubuntu:~/EasyRSA-3.0.4$ ./easyrsa sign-req server server
Note: using Easy-RSA configuration from: ./vars
Easy-RSA error:
Missing expected CA file: index.txt (perhaps you need to run build-ca?)
Run easyrsa without commands for usage and command help.
```

Comment: i think you missed the following points in step 3: **Start by navigating to the EasyRSA directory on your OpenVPN server:** and later on **Next, on your CA machine, navigate to the EasyRSA directory:** as i can see from your terminal log you are not switching the machine. They are using different colors for each machine on their how to page.

Comment: Thanks for reply. After following your advice, I'm still getting the same error message. I'm not sure what they mean by "switching machines" or "navigate to your CA machine". I'm typing in everything via ssh from my macbook in order. I just rebooted the NUC and I'm still getting the same error message :(

Comment: i am sorry james, but i am not going to reproduce the steps to see if the same error happens to me too. They seem to be using two seperate machines. one for CA building and one as server that needs to have these CA's stored in the end. Actl you are building the CA file on your server and receive the failing when you try to import it back to your server. I suggest you ignore these steps and jump from step *Copy the server key to the /etc/openvpn/ directory:*  directly to step *copy the server.crt and ca.crt files into your /etc/openvpn/ directory:*

Comment: AlexOnLinux. Unfortunately after following your instructions I'm still getting the error messages. However I did notice that after typing in "./easyrsa init-pki" I do not get the same output as digital ocean. This is what I get instead: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k04m1ygyadbbvsb/Screen%20Shot%202019-05-29%20at%209.56.01%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: you receive this message because you already created the credentials (ca.crt ca.key etc.) in your previous attempts. The tutorial from digital ocean shows you the output when you do not have any credentials stored and run this tool for first time.

Answer (score 5):

It's easy to miss the part of having to run build-ca as a command line option to easyrsa. You can try building `./easyrsa build-ca` and set password, in case you did not set this.

Comment: @Nmath I find that answer pretty self explanatory - also I know that easyrsa shows instructions when run too, and has adequate documentation - and it's easy to miss the part of having to run build-ca as a command line option to easyrsa.